# How to disable specific values from input type range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to create an intput of type range and disable some values from it ?
Like having a slider from 0 to 100 and disable 0 and 100 because I want to select 0 and 100 only by using checkbox. So the user can slide from 1 to 99 and need to use the checkboxes to get 0 or 100.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="priority-box"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI has something built in specifically for that.

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
```

Hope this helps!

HTML5 Solution: (IE support for only 9+)
http://jsfiddle.net/3aV5p/1/

Comment: So it's not possible in native javascript ? or basic jQuery ?

Comment: It should be, with a little more work. I'll see what I can come up with

Comment: Are you worried about support for previous than IE9 support?

Comment: Technicaly no, but I have solved the problem. My checkbox "max" set `.val("100")` and "min" set `.val("0")` in js. My slider goes from 1 to 99, and the value 100 and 0 are properly saved even if it's out of the scope. I mark you as the answer if it can help.

Comment: I added an HTML5 solution in the answer for you. The range slider is native to 5 but has little IE support.

Answer (score 1):

Try use the slide event in jQuery UI with fixed maximum [(http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-slide)](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemax) ..

You set the minimum and maximum range in the script. This is from the source:

```
...

$(function() {
$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
range: "max",
min: 1,
max: 99,
value: 2,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
}
});

...
```